# transient analysis inductor voltage

Tags: inductor, transient

In transient analysis, when at steady state, the inductors behave like a short circuit. Can I apply the voltage divider rule, to find the voltage drop across the inductors in series?

Comment: "in transient analysis when in steady state": That's a contradiction. Are you doing a steady-state analysis, or a transient analysis? They are opposite things.

Comment: Also, how would you build a voltage divider out of shorts? that makes little sense, either!

Comment: Welcome to the site. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Inductors don't behave like shorts at steady state, they behave like their winding resistances.

You can then apply the voltage divider rule : that then tells you about their winding resistances, which says nothing useful about the inductance.

And per Marcus' comment, ideal inductors have zero winding resistance so this is only useful with real inductors, or at least models that include the resistive component.